# Recommendations for moving from Npgqsql in .Net to .Net Core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, npgsql

I need to move my class library from .net 4.6.1 to .net core 1.1. I've been able to get everything except for npgsql to be compatible with 1.1. Is there a solution for npgsql or should I look for another library? Recommendations if I need to choose another library?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Perhaps you can edit your question to tell us what you tried, and any errors you got.  Did you take a look at http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 1.x is more or less considered deprecated, and everyone is being encouraged by Microsoft to move to .NET Core 2.x (important Microsoft libraries no longer target it). You should definitely consider targeting .NET Standard 2.0 if at all possible - any specific reason you're looking at .NET Core 1.x?

If you really do need .NET Core 1.x, then you can try using Npgsql 3.2.x, which still targeted .NET Standard 1.3. That version no longer receives much attention - so again you should not be doing this unless absolutely necessary - but the option is there.